# Testing Unity Games for iOS without an Ipad

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to develop an iPad game in Unity. I'm wondering if theres a way to test the app without using an iPad. I'm aware of a few different iOS simulators, most prominently iPadian, but whenever I search for any web references on using it to test games I develop I usually just get a guide telling me how to use the app store. Is there anyone who can shed some light on how this can be done, or whether its possible or not?

Comment: iPadian is not an iOS simulator like the one provided by Apple. iPadian simulates the look and feel of an iOS device, but does not actually run any Objective-C. You can only simulate an iOS device through a Mac running Xcode.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. Maybe my terminology was wrong, but is there any program or means by which I can develop an ipad app and test it on my pc? Specifically I was going to use Unity to develop it, if that helps at all.